# Mac mini failed to create activation request when trying to reset my local password on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, mac, ventura

I don't remember my login password so I followed the instructions in MacOS to reset the password with my Apple ID, now it's stuck at this Recovery Assistant interface and says Failed to create activation request, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you got [Activation Lock](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208987) enabled?

Comment: Are you certain that this Mac is associated with the Apple ID you used to reset the password?

Comment: @Allan yes, otherwise I wouldn't be stuck at this Recovery Assistant

Comment: @Thinkr I've already removed my Mac mini device from icloud, nothing changes

Comment: If the Apple IDs were different, you could run into this, but proceeding forward.. when you did recovery, was it local or did it download from the internet? Are you connected to WiFi and can reach outside your router?  Is it possible to connect to Ethernet (wired)?

Comment: @Allan I did try Ethernet